# Deriving the general equation of a plane without using vectors

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, alternative-proof, solid-geometry

I'm interested in finding the general form of the equation of a plane, using Cartesian coordinates. I know the answer to this is that any given plane is described by the equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$.

However, most derivations of the above equation employ the use of a vector perpendicular to the given plane. Is there a derivation which depends only on knowledge of Euclidean and analytic geometry, without using vectors? If yes, I would really appreciate seeing such a derivation.

Comment: Intersecting a plane with a plane parallel to a coordinate plane, you get a line. Hence, substituting $x=k$ or $y=k$ or $z=k$ into the equation of a plane you must get a linear equation. Hence the equation of a plane is itself linear.

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca you're making a very good point. Could you perhaps make it more rigorous and elaborate on it to form an answer?

Comment: You may use intersections with the axis to derive the plan equation. The trouble is that not all cases are covered.